# Sending group emails from gmail app in my nexus 10

Tags: gmail

How do I send a group email from gmail app. The group name is not recognised. Have tried from people as well and cannot work out how to do it. In my android phone it works from my group contacts list.

Answer (score 1):

GMail App didn't have this option yet.

You can try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groupu.android&hl=en) App. Its called contacts `GroupU`.
It will list all Groups and just press and hold on any group and select `send Email`.
Then there will be a pop up with `Gmail app` listed in it.
Select it. You are done.